# EntryPointNotFoundException in kernel32.dll SetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I'm running a c# application on mac using mono and xamarin as the IDE.
In my main method i have:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling=false)]
 public static extern bool SetEnvironmentVariable(string lpName, string lpValue);
```

and then when i call it:

```
SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path);
```

i get an EntryPointNotFoundException

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SetEnvironmentVariable
at at (wrapper managed-to-native) EICService.Program:SetEnvironmentVariable (string,string)
at EICService.Program.Main (System.String[] rawArgs) [0x00031] in (*my path*)/Program.cs:34
```

now i know that calling kernel32.dll on mac is a problem, but i assume that it is finding it or whatever mono has as a replacement for it because if i put some dummy dll file name there i get a dll not found error.

i'm very much a noob with c#, but this code runs on windows, we just want to have it running on unix.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Windows API function. It simply does not exist on a Mac. Hence the error.

You don't need to p/invoke this function to set a variable in the process environment. You can use the native .net functionality. That is `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`.

What's more, you should be doing exactly the same on Windows. It's never a good idea to p/invoke a native function to perform functionality offered by the .net runtime libraries.

Comment: is System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable the same as Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable?

Comment: Yes it is. I omitted the `System` namespace in the answer, for sake of being more concise.

Comment: Btw, I note that you've asked 17 questions, accepted no answers and voted only 4 times. Perhaps you might engage a bit more with the community.

Comment: ohh, sorry i didnt know im supposed to accept answeres... and vote... :) will do from now on!

Comment: Thanks. You might review your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3058468/ido-flax?tab=questions